# PHP GET method space error

Tags: php, html, get

```
<?php

$current_subject = $_GET['subject_id'];
$current_content = $_GET['note_id'];

echo "<form method=\"post\" action=mainpage.php?subject_id=".$current_subject."&note_id=".$current_content.">";

?> 
  <input type='text' name='list_item' value=''>
  <input type='submit' name="new_item" value="New Item">   
</form>
```

The problem is that when one of the `GET` variables is two words the link doesn't write it that way. So for example if `$current_subject="Advanced Chemistry"` and `$current_content="Valence Electrons"` the link will come out as:

```
<form method=​"post" action=​"mainpage.php?subject_id=Advanced" chemistry&note_id=​"Valence" electrons>​
```

Comment: +1 For a clear, concise question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to [`urlencode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the variables like so:

```
<?php

$current_subject = $_GET['subject_id'];
$current_content = $_GET['note_id'];

$subject = urlencode($current_subject);
$content = urlencode($current_content);

$action = "mainpage.php?subject_id=" . $subject . "&note_id=" . $content;

?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $action; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="list_item" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="new_item" value="New Item">   
</form>
```

Also, you should get in the habit of validating that data. You probably want to check that they are integers.

Comment: You've misplaced urlencode: `echo urlencode("mainpage.php?subject_id=1234 łóść&note_id=absd saas")` gives `mainpage.php%3Fsubject_id%3D1234+%C5%82%C3%B3%C5%9B%C4%87%26note_id%3Dabsd+saas`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! Now fixed. Been awhile since I've worked in PHP.

Answer (score 4):

Use `urlencode()` or `rawurlencode()`

Answer (score 3):

*Always* quote your attributes and escape your data. Quoted, it would work:

```
<?php

$current_subject = $_GET['subject_id'];
$current_content = $_GET['note_id'];

echo "<form method=\"post\" action=\"mainpage.php?subject_id=" . $current_subject . "&note_id=" . $current_content . "\">";

?> 
    <input type="text" name="list_item" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="new_item" value="New Item" />   
</form>
```

But, of course, you should `urlencode` it first:

```
<?php
$current_subject = $_GET['subject_id'];
$current_content = $_GET['note_id'];
$url = 'mainpage.php?subject_id=' . urlencode($current_subject) . '&note_id=' . urlencode($current_content);
?> 
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $url; ?>">
    <input type="text" name="list_item" value="" />
    <input type="submit" name="new_item" value="New Item" />   
</form>
```

Comment: It looks like you forgot the double quotes around {$url} in the second code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query):

```
$query = http_build_query(array('subject_id' => $_GET['subject_id'], 'foo' => 'bar'));
<form action="mainpage.php?<?php echo $query; ?>">
```

I have a suspicion that `$query` should also be `htmlentities`'d.
The `http_build_query` handles the URI encoding, but I'm not sure if it should also be HTML-encoded on top of that (it is an HTML attribute after all).

Comment: Don't worry about using `htmlentities`, anything that it escapes is also invalid in URLs.

Comment: Meaning that http_build_query (or urlencode) will have already escaped any htmlentities?  That's what I thinking, but was not sure.  If that is the case though, there would be no harm in calling htmlentities on it again.  Just a waste of effort :).

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at PHPs [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$current_subject = urlencode($_GET['subject_id']);
$current_content = urlencode($_GET['note_id']);
```